# Reset/Refresh Search Form Button in WordPress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming, reset

First time posting. I appreciate any help in advance. I really appreciate it.

I am currently work with a wordpress theme to search villas around the world and I would love to add a reset button that would clear the fields, drop downs and check boxes that are populated by a custom fields app. The normal reset button does not work and since I am teaching myself PHP on the fly I am at a loss. Here is the link to the page and I will paste some of the code so you get an idea of what I am looking at.

I really appreciate any help since the theme author has been blowing me off.

[LINK](http://villa1.froschft2.com/home-property-map/)

```html
<?php
 global $realty_theme_option, $wp_query;
?>

<form class="property-search-form border-box" action="<?php if ( tt_page_id_template_search() ) { echo get_permalink( tt_page_id_template_search() ); } ?>">

 <div class="row">

  <?php if ( isset( $realty_theme_option['property-search-results-page'] ) && empty( $realty_theme_option['property-search-results-page'] ) ) { ?>
   <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 1em">
    <p class="alert alert-info"><?php esc_html_e( 'Please go to "Appearance > Theme Options > Pages" and set the page you want to use as your property search results.', 'realty' ); ?></p>
   </div>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php
   // Form select classes
   $form_select_class = 'form-control';

   if ( $realty_theme_option['enable-rtl-support'] || is_rtl() ) {
    $form_select_class .= ' chosen-select chosen-rtl';
   } else {
    $form_select_class .= ' chosen-select';
   }

   $acf_field_array = array();

   if ( isset( $realty_theme_option['property-search-features'] ) && ! tt_is_array_empty( $realty_theme_option['property-search-features'] ) ) {
      $property_search_features = $realty_theme_option['property-search-features'];
   } else {
    $property_search_features = null;
   }

   $raw_search_params = get_query_var( 'property_search_parameters' );
   if ( ! tt_is_array_empty( $raw_search_params ) ) {
    $search_parameters = $raw_search_params;
   } else if ( isset( $realty_theme_option['property-search-parameter'] ) && ! empty( $realty_theme_option['property-search-parameter'] ) ) {
    $search_parameters = $realty_theme_option['property-search-parameter'];
   } else {
    $search_parameters = null;
   }

   $raw_search_fields = get_query_var('property_search_fields');
   if ( ! tt_is_array_empty( $raw_search_fields ) ) {
    $search_fields = $raw_search_fields;
   } else if ( isset( $realty_theme_option['property-search-parameter'] ) && ! empty( $realty_theme_option['property-search-parameter'] ) ) {
    $search_fields = $realty_theme_option['property-search-field'];
   } else {
    $search_fields = null;
   }

   $raw_search_labels = get_query_var('property_search_labels');
   if ( ! tt_is_array_empty( $raw_search_labels ) ) {
    $search_labels = $raw_search_labels;
   } else if ( isset( $realty_theme_option['property-search-label'] ) && ! empty( $realty_theme_option['property-search-label'] ) ) {
    $search_labels = $realty_theme_option['property-search-label'];
   }  else {
    $search_labels = null;
   }

   $default_search_fields_array = array(
    'estate_search_by_keyword',
    'estate_property_id',
    'estate_property_location',
    'estate_property_type',
    'estate_property_status',
    'estate_property_price',
    'estate_property_price_min',
    'estate_property_price_max',
    'estate_property_pricerange',
    'estate_property_size',
    'estate_property_rooms',
    'estate_property_bedrooms',
    'estate_property_bathrooms',
    'estate_property_garages',
    'estate_property_available_from'
   );

   $i = 0;

   if ( isset( $search_form_columns ) && ! empty( $search_form_columns ) ) {
    // Use $columns parameter from shortcode [property_search_form]
    $count_search_fields = $search_form_columns;
   } else {
    // No shortcode $columns found, pick columns according to total field count
    $count_search_fields = count( $search_fields );
   }

   if ( $count_search_fields == 1 ) {
    $columns = 'col-xs-12';
   } else if ( $count_search_fields == 2 ) {
    $columns = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6';
   } else if ( $count_search_fields == 3 ) {
    $columns = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4';
   } else {
    $columns = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3';
   }

   if ( is_page_template( 'template-map-vertical.php' ) ) {
    $columns = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6';
   }

   // Do we have any search parameters defined?
   if ( isset( $search_parameters ) && ! empty( $search_parameters[0] ) ) {

    foreach ( $search_fields as $search_field ) {

     $search_parameter = $search_parameters[$i];

     // Check If Search Field Is Filled Out
     if ( ! empty( $search_field ) ) {

      // Default Property Field
      if ( in_array( $search_field, $default_search_fields_array ) ) {

       switch ( $search_field ) {

        case 'estate_search_by_keyword' :
        case 'estate_property_id' :
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $columns; ?> form-group">
         <input type="text" name="<?php echo $search_parameter; ?>" id="<?php echo $search_parameter; ?>" value="<?php echo isset( $_GET[$search_parameter]) ? $_GET[$search_parameter] : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $search_labels[$i]; ?>" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <?php
        break;

        case 'estate_property_location' : ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $columns; ?> form-group select">
         <?php
          // http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14652/how-to-show-a-hierarchical-terms-list#answer-14658
          if ( ! empty( $search_labels[$i] ) ) {
           $search_label_location = $search_labels[$i];
          } else {
           $search_label_location = esc_html__( 'Any Location', 'realty' );
          }
         ?>
         <select name="<?php echo $search_parameter; ?>" id="<?php echo $search_parameter; ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $form_select_class ); ?>">
          <option value="all"><?php echo $search_label_location; ?></option>
            <?php
             $location = get_terms('property-location', array(
              'orderby' => 'slug',
              'parent' => 0,
              'hide_empty' => false
             ) );

             if ( isset( $_GET[$search_parameter] ) ) {
            $get_location = $_GET[$search_parameter];
           } else {
            $get_location = null;
           }
          ?>

            <?php foreach ( $location as $key => $location ) : ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $location->slug; ?>" <?php selected( $location->slug, $get_location ); ?>>
                 <?php
                  echo $location->name;

                  $location2 = get_terms( 'property-location', array(
                   'orderby' => 'slug',
                   'parent' => $location->term_id
                  ) );

                  if ( $location2 ) :
                 ?>
                 <optgroup>
                   <?php foreach( $location2 as $key => $location2 ) : ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $location2->slug; ?>" class="level2" <?php selected( $location2->slug, $get_location ); ?>>
                        <?php
                         echo $location2->name;

                         $location3 = get_terms( 'property-location', array(
                          'orderby' => 'slug',
                          'parent' => $location2->term_id
                         ) );

                         if ( $location3 ) :
                        ?>
                        <optgroup>
                         <?php foreach( $location3 as $key => $location3 ) : ?>
                           <option value="<?php echo $location3->slug; ?>" class="level3" <?php selected( $location3->slug, $get_location ); ?>>
                           <?php
                           echo $location3->name;
                           $location4 = get_terms( 'property-location', array( 'orderby' => 'slug', 'parent' => $location3->term_id ) );
                           if( $location4 ) :
                           ?>
                           <optgroup>
                            <?php foreach( $location4 as $key => $location4 ) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $location4->slug; ?>" class="level4" <?php selected( $location4->slug, $get_location ); ?>>
                  <?php echo $location4->name; ?>
                            </option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                           </optgroup>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                           </option>
                         <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </optgroup>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                       </option>
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
                 </optgroup>
                 <?php endif; ?>
              </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
         </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: I can see some javascript errors coming up in the console when you press the reset button.  To clear all the form values I'd write some jQuery or javascript code that is executed on clicking the reset button.

Answer (score 0):

There's a line of code that needs modifying

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('form_[form_key]').reset();" autocomplete="off">Reset Form</a>
```

That element does not exist, the form has a class called `property-search-form` which you could use as the selector.

So replace the line with something like

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('property-search-form').reset();" autocomplete="off">Reset Form</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Appreciate the response. Now I just need to get the javascript to run. I have never edited a theme this much.

Comment: Not really ideal having to edit the theme as any updates to it will overwrite your modifications.